# Book of Esther's major theme is that God's people may have Unwillingly strayed away from God, but God is still Loving towards said people

Tags: historical-interpretation, esther, cultural-analysis

I'm trying to approach the Book of Esther in the Bible in a holistic manner ( taking a bird's eye view ) of God's varying calibrated auspices of His chosen Israelite nation.
Also I am taking into account the historical/cultural contexts for the time period and region in question.

Esther and Mordecai, and also possibly their exiled Jewish community  in the Perisan empire may **Not** have had an intimate relationship with the God of Israel at the beginning of the story of Esther.  Also, they might Not have been religious either.  In other words, they did **Not** grow up in a social/cultural/religious environment of the legalistic Pharisees who challenged Jesus Christ in the Gospels.

Here is an explanation as to why I put forth the aforementioned statements:

1. Many bible readers and Theologians already know that God is Not mentioned in the Book of Esther.
2. Esther 2:8-18 passage of scripture has strong circumstantial evidence suggesting/hinting that  Esther had pre-marital sex with King Ahasuerus
   ( Reference:  https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/44048/in-esther-28-18-what-would-ahashuerus-harem-been-like-during-the-time-of-es   )
3. Esther who is Jewish ended up marrying King Ahasuerus who is a NonJew.  Furthermore, the Book of Esther does Not mention Esther and/or Mordecai protesting and/or resisting Esther's marriage to King Ahasuerus
4. Now I'm going to make an big assumption by saying that the exiled Jewish community may have lost or had a weakened intimacy with God or No religious/legalistic approach to God due to fact that being in exile may have caused them to become distant from God possibly due to:

   a) oppression from their conquerors to abandon their Jewish faith in order to integrate into the conquerors empires.

   Or

   b) Or maybe even the fact that they went into exile in other empires which were far away from the physical land of Israel, and they just started adopting more of the cultural norms/practices/mores of said empires
   ( However, this aspect is a big assumption on my part. )

Basically, I'm trying to emphasise that God's Loving, Compassionate, Gracious has a large enough bounded area that is gracious and compassionate enough for God to take into consideration as to whether the Ancient Israelite nation is undergoing a particular phase/state in time where they do Not have an intimate relationship with God, and therefore, He still delivers/protects them against their enemies and liberates them.

In other words, God is compassionate and gracious enough to take into consideration the person who might have grown up in a broken home that led him/her to a world of illicit substance addiction and/or alcoholism, and therefore, God will approach said person with  correlated varying calibrated auspices that should lead him/her to deliverance, protection and liberation.

( Side Note, the word God's "Equity" is relevant here, therefore, the following bible verse and picture illustration are incidentally relevant for this posting:

> Proverbs 2:9 New American Standard Bible 1995
>
> 9  Then you will discern righteousness and justice And **equity** and
> every good course.

Credit Reference for picture illustration below:  https://www.mentalfloss.com/article/625404/equity-vs-equality-what-is-the-difference

[image]

Esther and Mordecai may Not have had an intimate relationship with God, but God still delivered and protected them from their enemies.

( Side Note: I suppose a verse that might be relevant to this posting is

> James 4:17
>
> 17 Therefore, to one who knows the right thing to do and does Not do
> it, to him it is sin.

)

To conclude, the Book of Esther's major theme is that God's people may have unintentionally/unwillingly strayed away from God, but God is still Loving, Compassionate, Gracious and Caring towards said people.

Is the aforementioned evaluation/assessment correct?

Comment: Gods name (Yahweh) *is* in the book of Esther - quite clearly in fact - acrostically. More than once. In fact, the ‘pattern’ reflects clear intent, design (inspiration), really very interesting! (REF: http://www.wpo-gregor.org/files/bible-college-masters-notes-missler/Ruth-Esther-Missler.pdf ) Scroll down to page 109

Comment: If someone down votes then please specify your reasons

Comment: I haven't downvoted, but I'm on the fence about whether to downvote or close the question... this is a really odd question format - you've essentially provided a thesis and asked "is this right?", which isn't really the way the SE format works. Questions generally should focus on the text, and shouldn't shoe-horn a particular view into it. I'd suggest you'd be better splitting most of this text off as an 'Answer' to a shorter, more specific question, something like "What is the major theme of the Book of Esther?"

Comment: For the record, I did **not** downvote! Emphasis added because as I left a comment, the ‘finger’ may look to be pointing to me.

Comment: Few corrections, technically Mordechai was a pharisee. The king could choose whatever woman he wanted, and no one could protest. In judaism, women are not obliged to choose death upon forbidden relationships with a non-jew. So she did not had any other choice.

Answer (score 1):

Your theory proposes some interesting ideas, however, I found aspects of the Book of Esther that go against your theory.

1)

> (Esther 4:15-17)
>
> 15 Then Esther told them to reply to Mordecai, 16
> “Go, assemble all the Jews who are found in Susa, and fast for me; do
> not eat or drink for three days, night or day. I and my maidens also
> will fast in the same way. And thus I will go in to the king, which is
> not according to the law; and if I perish, I perish.” 17 So Mordecai
> went away and did just as Esther had commanded him.

Esther vow to fast, and her request for Mordecai and Susa's Jews to fast must seem to suggest that they must have believed in some kind of Divine God.  It would Not make sense for them to fast if they had a No intimate relationship or even a weak intimate relationship with God.

2.

> ( Esther 4:13-14 )
>
> 13 Then Mordecai told them to reply to Esther, “Do not imagine that
> you in the king’s palace can escape any more than all the Jews. 14 For
> if you remain silent at this time, relief and deliverance will arise
> for the Jews from another place and you and your father’s house will
> perish. And who knows whether you have not attained royalty for such a
> time as this?”

Mordecai tells Esther that even she remains silent during this crisis, there will be some kind of relief and deliverance that will arise for the Jews from another place which must suggests/hints/implies that Mordecai believed in some kind of Divine Power that will rescue the Jews.

3.

> (Esther 3:2-6)
>
> 2 All the king’s servants who were at the king’s gate bowed down
> [b]and paid homage to Haman; for so the king had commanded concerning
> him. But Mordecai neither bowed down nor paid homage. 3 Then the
> king’s servants who were at the king’s gate said to Mordecai, “Why are
> you transgressing the king’s command?” 4 Now it was when they had
> spoken daily to him and he would not listen to them, that they told
> Haman to see whether Mordecai’s reason would stand; for he had told
> them that he was a Jew. 5 When Haman saw that Mordecai neither bowed
> down nor paid homage to him, Haman was filled with rage. 6 But he
> disdained to lay hands on Mordecai alone, for they had told him who
> the people of Mordecai were; therefore Haman sought to destroy all the
> Jews, the people of Mordecai, who were throughout the whole kingdom of
> Ahasuerus.

As the bible verses above attest to Mordecai refusal to bow to Haman because Mordecai stated that Mordecai was a Jew, and therefore would Not bow down to Haman.  However, I suppose you could just say that Mordecai was emphasizing his own Jewish ancestry out of sense of some kind of quasi-Nonreligious patriotism/ethnocentrism pertaining to his own Jewish religious/ethnic background, but then again that also does suggest/hint at some kind of loyalty to the Jewish God.

Comment: In short, the absence of God's name is a red herring. Their faith was implicit.